# Send data privately to a url by button

Tags: javascript

My question is, I have 3 buttons and if I click on any of these three buttons, I want to send the values ​​in the `<li></li>` value to the `send.php` page. For example, I want to send the value 1 in the first button to the `send.php page` secretly. How can I listen to the buttons and get the values?

```
<div class="cards">
    <div class="card shadow">
      <ul>
        <li id="one" class="price bottom-bar">1</li>
        <li><a class="btn" href="" >Send</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>   
    <div class="card active">
      <ul>
        <li id="two" class="price bottom-bar">2</li>
        <li><a class="btn" href="" >Send</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="card shadow">
      <ul>
        <li id="three" class="price bottom-bar">3</li>
        <li><a class="btn" href="" >Send</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "secretly"?

Comment: If you mean do it without reloading the page, use AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that by

> Send data privately to a url

you mean send text via POST http method, in which the data is in the encrypted (if HTTPS) body section of the request rather than in the URL (like with the GET http method).

```js
const buttonList = [...document.getElementsByClassName("btn")];

function handleButtonClick(event, button) {
  const valueToSend = button.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("li").textContent;
  
  fetch("send.php", {
    method: "POST",
    body: valueToSend
  })
  .then(
    response=>console.log(`Message ${valueToSend} successfully sent! ${response.url} responsed with ${response.ok ? "success" : "error"} code ${response.status}.`),
    response=>console.log("There was an error sending the message.", response)
  );
  
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default link redirection
}

for (const button of buttonList) {
  button.addEventListener("click", e=>handleButtonClick(e, button));
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
    <div class="card shadow">
      <ul>
        <li id="one" class="price bottom-bar">1</li>
        <li><a class="btn" href="" >Send</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>   
    <div class="card active">
      <ul>
        <li id="two" class="price bottom-bar">2</li>
        <li><a class="btn" href="" >Send</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="card shadow">
      <ul>
        <li id="three" class="price bottom-bar">3</li>
        <li><a class="btn" href="" >Send</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Of course, this demo will display an error, as there is no php script set up on stackoverflow.com/send.php to receive the messages. Try running it on your site :)

Comment: thank you so much. So how can I afford this on the send.php page? So I need to get it as $_GET[] ? @asdf3.14159

Comment: You can get the value with `$value = file_get_contents('php://input');`. Then the variable `$value` will contain the sent value.